# Laravel 5.1. - Login sessions not persisting

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, cartalyst-sentinel

I am using laravel 5.1 with Sentinel - Cartalyst auth driver. Problem is that Laravel can't "keep" users logged in. After some time (when they visit website) it automatically kicks them out with error that they are not logged in (I have filter that checks if user is logged in for every route expect login route). It really bugs me and I can't fix it.
I tried using cookies, file and database driver for keeping login sessions and they all fail.

Does someone knows how to deal with this problem? I am bulding project for Intranet users (under local domain)... Maybe that could be problem? Also I notice that cookies expiration time is current datetime that laravels sets for max expiration time.

Comment: have you tried setting lifetime from config/session.php ?

Comment: @kunoichi I tried but problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you imported the correct namespace path to Cartalyst? I had an issue with sessions not persisting and it was caused by importing the native php Cartalyst class rather than the laravel one. It should be something like `Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel::class`